# joining multiple table and show the attribute name instead of id

Tags: mysql

**## choicelist table**

```
chl_element  chl_label    chl_dependent_value  chl_value
country      india                             IN
state        karnataka    IN                   KA
city         bangalore    KA                   BNG
```

**## entity Table**

```
ent_name
xyz
```

**## entity_locations **

```
elo_name
123
```

**## entity_department **

```
ede_name
abc
```

**## users **

```
usr_name
hundai
```

how can i join  all tables and shows the country name,state name,elo_name,etc,while using select * from users instead of id. i don't want to use sub queries because while searching it will create problem

Comment: How are the relations among tables defined?

Comment: users table have each tables id

Comment: Unless the names of fields are known, it is just a wild guess to give you a possible solution.

Comment: BTW: did you try any query?